# Jquery - Get the closest div and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched here in stackoverflow but didnt find a solution for my case..

i want to do a group div who will appear or will hide if the down button is clicked...have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>Relatorio</title>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>


</head>


<body style="border-top: solid 10px #ffffff" class="container">

    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div>                           

                            <div>

                                <div style="border:1px solid black;font-size:20px;overflow:auto;">              

                                        <div class="container" style="background-color:orangered;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    Relatorio 01
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="container" style="background-color:orangered;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;color: white">
                                            <div class="row" style="text-align:right;">
                                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                    field1
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align:right;">
                                                    <div id='botabrefecha'>
                                                        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="abrefecha" style="border:0px solid black;display:none">
                                            <div class="container" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        field2 Group
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align:right;">
                                                        <input type="text" style="width:100%;" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="container" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        field3 Group
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align:right;">
                                                        <input type="text" style="width:100%;" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                    

                                        </div>      

                                        <div class="container" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    txtCampo3
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align:right;">
                                                    <input type="text" style="width:100%;" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>   

                                </div>
                            </div>      

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

and this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                $('#botabrefecha').on('click', function () {

                    var visivel = $(this).closest('div').find(".abrefecha").is(":visible");

                    if (visivel)
                    {

                        $(this).closest('div').find(".abrefecha").hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).closest('div').find(".abrefecha").show();
                    }            

                });            

            });
```

but i dont know why he cant show or hide my div. i have tested and he returns if is visible or not...but when i try to show or hide, nothing happens...

any ideas?

Thanks!

Rafael

Comment: your selection gets the closest div and then searches if it or its content has the class "abrefecha". But the closest div doesn't have any. Try with `$(this).closest('div.abrefecha')` rather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code there is only one div containing the class `abrefecha` so you can access that element directly. For show/hide of elements you can use jQuery's toggle function.

[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

You can access that div directly in your click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#botabrefecha').on('click', function () {
        $('.abrefecha').toggle();   
    });            
});
```

Comment: but if i add more elements with this class? will works too?

Comment: because it will add elements dinamically, so in certains screens, i will have more elements with this class...

Comment: it would then toggle all of them, you can then either set an id attribute for each specific group or specific classes and the toggle them as you want. Only update the selector in the click handler with the new class/id

Comment: ah ok..i will try this! Thanks!